# Not able to perform action on push notification custom buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, push-notification

I am working on an iOS application which involves device to device push notification. In Foreground and Background state, I am able to receive notification and able to perform respective actions in respective custom buttons (ACCEPT & REJECT). Everything works fine in the two mentioned states. But in killed/terminated state, although I am able to receive notification, but I am not able to perform action on clicking custom buttons (ACCEPT & REJECT). Can you guys help me this?[image: Notification screenshot with Custom buttons Accept and Reject]

```
//Notification action button function
func setActionCategories(){
    let acceptAction = UNNotificationAction(
        identifier: NAString().notificationAcceptIdentifier(),
        title: NAString().accept().capitalized,
        options: [.init(rawValue: 0)])

    let rejectAction = UNNotificationAction(
        identifier: NAString().notificationRejectIdentifier(),
        title: NAString().reject().capitalized,
        options: [.init(rawValue: 0)])

    let actionCategory = UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: NAString().notificationActionCategory(),
        actions: [acceptAction,rejectAction],
        intentIdentifiers: [],
        options: [.customDismissAction])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(
        [actionCategory])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    //Here we are performing Action on Notification Buttons & We created this buttons in  "setActionCategories" function.
    if response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier == NAString().notificationActionCategory() {

        //Created Firebase reference to get currently invited visitor by E-Intercom
        var gateNotificationRef : DatabaseReference?
        gateNotificationRef = GlobalUserData.shared.getUserDataReference().child(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_GATE_NOTIFICATION).child(userUID).child(guestType!).child(guestUID!)

        //Performing accept & reject on click of recently invited visitor by E-Intercom from Notification view.
        switch response.actionIdentifier {

        //If Accept button will pressed
        case NAString().notificationAcceptIdentifier():
            gateNotificationRef?.child(NAString().status()).setValue(NAString().accepted())
            }
            break

        //If Reject button will pressed
        case NAString().notificationRejectIdentifier():                                                         gateNotificationRef?.child(NAString().status()).setValue(NAString().rejected())
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: In my case i'm not getting notification in killed state? How you've done this? I've set content-available :1 in my payload. Though it's not displaying notification in killed state.

Comment: Can you show me your payload?

Comment: I am facing the same challenge? Have you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ashish can you provide some code for us to better assist you.  There should be a completion handler in there where you can add an action function. Then you can perform whatever you need the buttons to do.

Comment: I have updated my post with the Code. Please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below condition in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate

```
if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
    // Do what you want to do when remote notification is tapped.
}
```

you can call `didReceive` delegate method in it.

Comment: I don't have to tap on notification. I have to tap on the action categories (ACCEPT AND REJECT)

Comment: Ok, when the app is in background if you are tapping accept, which method will get called first? isn't didReceive?